# DevDays 2011 price just went up?

Tags: discussion, devdays-2011

I was looking at the registration page for DevDays 2011 in Washington DC last week, and the registration price was listed at $399. Today it's $499. I'm surprised; did I miss an early-bird deadline or something? It seems early for the price to be increasing. Is there a registration deadline coming up that I should know about? I'm hoping my company will pay the registration fee for me to attend, but it's hard to convince my boss when the price suddenly leaps over what I originally told her.

Comment: @systempuntoout - Washington DC still shows $499 when I look at it: [link](http://devdayswashingtondc-site.eventbrite.com/) . Are you sure you're not looking at a different venue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you participate in meta and did NOT attend DevDays last time, use the discount code "meta" for $100 off.

Comment: Are you verifying meta participation from users who use that code? Because *that would be awesome*.

Comment: careful, you might find yourself volunteering for a rather thankless, mindless, and drab administrative job.

Comment: I do have a tendency to do that!

Comment: Thanks again for the discount code. I just registered for Washington DC and my boss did indeed agree to reimburse me for it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the price went up. If you attended the 2009 DevDays, you will receive an email with a code that will drop your price by $100, bringing it back to the previous level (at least for the DC venue; some of the other venues have gone up even further).

BTW, I have no standing to speak officially. The above is just my own observations on this matter. :-)

Comment: The $100 code is true for London too.

Comment: @Jon: What, you mean the code will bring the London venue to original price? ;-)